# aws ec2 files changes not reflected

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-ec2, timeout

I made a change on ec2 ssh files util.js but the changes are not reflected on server

I went to my client folder and cd src/helpers/util.js and used `sudo nano util.js`and then I updated the code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getTokenFromCookie } from './authValidation';

const API_BASE_URL = 'http://22.45.23.23:8080'; //updated the url here

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
});

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = getTokenFromCookie();
  if (token) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});

export default api;
```

now when I go to website its referring to old url still when I try to login any reason why changes are not reflected? I even restarted the ngnix server

[image]

Comment: Does your webapp require a build?  Have you cleared your browsers cache?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  yes i cleared my browser cache and i build as well npm build run and it compiled succesfully but still no changes reflected